# Unable to get record in Lightning Datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

I am trying to display records from Contact Object in a Lightning Component in a datatable. Somehow the records are not getting displayed. Can someone please help where am I going wrong?

Apex Controller:

```
public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(){
        return [Select Id, Name, Phone, Email From Contact];
    }
}
```

Lightning Component 'displayContacts':

```
<aura:component controller="ContactController" >
<aura:attribute name="myData" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="myColumns" type="List"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
<lightning:datatable data="{!v.myData}"
        columns="{!v.myColumns}"
        keyField="Id"
        hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
```

Component controller js:

```
({
init : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    cmp.set('v.myColumns',[
        {label: 'Contact Name', fieldname: 'Name', type:'text'},
        {label: 'Phone', fieldname: 'Phone', type:'phone'},
        {label: 'Email', fieldname: 'Email', type:'email'},
    ]);
    helper.getData(cmp);
}
```

})

Component helper Js:

```
({
getData : function(cmp) {
    var action = cmp.get('c.getContacts');
    action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set('v.myData', response.getReturnValue());
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            console.error(errors);
        }
    }));
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a case issue with your code:

```
cmp.set('v.myColumns',[
        {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'Name', type:'text'},
        {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type:'phone'},
        {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type:'email'},
    ]);
```

fieldname => fieldName